# How do I get a list of two different categories of vocabulary in drupal7?

Tags: views

I have a content type, there are two terms Term reference in different categories,I would like to have a related post block and the relevant posts of the two term references are the same.

I use views, can only be related to a classification, another classification using conditional filtering, but the conditions can not be filtered dynamic call, this is not what I want!

What should I do, please help me, thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: You want to follow my answer there, except for step 3, select `Filter to items that share ALL terms`

Comment: Yes, thanks to your success. Thank you very much!No Sssweat